# use javascript to copy input values to another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a asp.net form, which is using two Person usercontrols, one named 'BillingInfo' and one named 'ShippingInfo'. The person usercontrol has a "Address" input field that has the class set to "address1". On my order page, how can I assign the value of one Address field into the other using javascript? The dynamic IDs are throwing me off. Each control is inside of a div, titled "ShippingContactInfo" and "BillingContactInfo" respectively.
The function is firing, and when executing, the objects are being populated, but for some reason the value assignment is not doing anything on the page.

I have tried:

```
  function copyBillingAddress(f) {
    if (copyBillingCheckBox.checked == true) {
        var addrCopyFromVal = $('#ShippingContactInfo .address1').value;
        var addrCopyTo = $('#BillingContactInfo .address1');
        addrCopyTo.val(addrCopyFromVal.val());
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It should be `.val()` not `.value` on a jquery object.

You can use the `val()` as getter as well as `val(somevalue)` as setter as you are using already.

```
    var addrCopyFromVal = $('#ShippingContactInfo .address1').val(); //<-- Here
    var addrCopyTo = $('#BillingContactInfo .address1');
    addrCopyTo.val(addrCopyFromVal); // <-- And here
```

or just simply write:

```
$('#BillingContactInfo .address1').val($('#ShippingContactInfo .address1').val());
```

See [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use through change event of **copyBillingCheckBox**

```
$("#copyBillingCheckBox").change(function(){

        if(this.checked)
        {
           $('#BillingContactInfo .address1').val($('#ShippingContactInfo .address1').val());
        }
        else{
             $('#BillingContactInfo .address1').val("");
        }

    });
```